# How to customise or control the Windows Explorer tree view

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I would like that whenever I open a Windows explorer, I can somewhere set which folders should be expanded and which collapsed.  E.g. *Libraries* is always expanded, and seldom used.  It makes me have to scroll up and down between *Computer* and *Favourites*, being some nuisance.

Can I do this, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Control Panel open the 'Appearance and Personalization' then the  'Folder Options'
in the 'General tab' at the bottom in the Navigation pane un-click 'Show all folders'.

[image: win 7 folder options]

The Navigation pane should now look like this.

[image: After shot of explorer]

You could always try >click the expand arrow so that the Libraries are non-expanded and then close it.    When opened this will keep the Libraries compacted.(Same as when you close explorer at a size and when you open explorer it will open at that same size)
Another option is a free program called 'Windows 7 Navigation Pane Customizer' from
http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-navigation-pane-customizer-show-hide-rename-items-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane/.

[image: win7 free program]
You can un-click the libraries check box
I found it in 'Help desk geek'
http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/easily-add-and-remove-items-from-the-explorer-navigation-pane-in-windows-7/